# Using lambda as dry-run option sane?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, concurrency

I am looking for a good implementation for a dry-run runtime option, so that the results from a computation are *not* written to disc, but discarded without interfering with the rest of the code. Currently I have this:

```
void write(queue_type &queue, bool dry_run, const struct options &opts){
  auto dataset = opts.dataset;
  buffer_type buf;
  auto dwrite = dry_run
    ?[](Dataset &, const buffer_type &){}
    :[](Dataset &dset, const buffer_type &buf){dset.write(buf);}
  while(queue.pop(buf)){
    dwrite(dataset, buf);
  }
}

int main() {
  /* ... */;
  bool dry_run = /*...*/;
  queue_type queue{};
  struct options opts{...};
  std:thread(write, std::ref(queue), dry_run, std::cref(opts));
  for(...){
    /* fill queue */
    queue.append(...);
  }
}
```

*dataset* is a handler to an open file. *queue* is feeding the *write(bool dry_run,...)* thread with data. So in essence, this function should only pop some data from queue and (dry) write it.

Is there another way to implement this, I got the feeling this is not very elegant. I hope this suffices as an example.

Is using std::function or a function pointer here better?

Comment: What is a "dry-run option"?

Comment: @NeilButterworth the one which writes nothing, of course.

Comment: With dry-run, I mean doing a the computation, but when I comes to writing the data to disc, it should skip this actual writing. So no byte is being written

Comment: I would say a good implementation would not require you to pass `bool dry_run` everywhere. Maybe you can make `write` itself a function pointer and let it point to the appropriate function depending on `dry_run` so outside of `main` setting up the `write` pointer no other code comes into contact with `dry_run`.

Comment: The good practice here would be designing and implementing an _interface_ class for doing the writing. A `writer` interface class would be implemented in classes like `file_writer`, `db_writer`, `null_writer` etc. When doing a "dry-run", the `null_writer` would be instantiated and given to the thread (which should of course actually be another class, call it `processor`, instead of a raw function in a thread) that processes the data. This is known as _Strategy Pattern_. The same thing of course can be done with templates where the writer is given to the `processor` class as a template param.

Comment: @Etherealone there is nothing good in this proliferation of unnecessary polymorphism.

Comment: @SergeyA There is if you are doing anything serious. Otherwise adding a feature will result in flags and if-else's everywhere in the long run, ending up in a time consuming proper re-design. Or worse, the chaotic code will keep building up because clueless management will have _no time/resources_ for a redesign, yet doing any simple 1-day modifications will take 1-week of code inspection and adding random stuff to sparse places.

Comment: BTW, note that dwrite already is a function pointer; your lambdas are implicitly converted to a function pointer via "?:", just because they have the same signature ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes ok, yeah I think I stumbled across this, when I tried to use lambda captures there. I got a very weird error and decided to leave it alone that for some time.

Comment: Do you have C++14?

Comment: Nope, Uni compiler is too old :/ What would have been the benefit of using C++14?

Comment: @SergeyA I suggest taking a look at golang, which makes extensive use of such interfaces, and the language is beautiful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is elegant, but I would make it even more elegant by making an implementation function which would be templatized on boolean argument.

The reason being, in your case `dwrite` becomes a function pointer and later called through indirection. This is sub-performant on multiple iterations (I assume you have those since why would you have a thread otherwise?).

The way I would do it would be:

```
template<bool dry_run> void write_impl(/* all args but dry run */) {
...
}

void write(/* args */) {
    return dry_run ? write_impl<true>(/* args */) : write_impl<false>(/* args */);
}
```

Comment: Ah, so in a sense just writing two functions, and when it comes to std::thread just do a if(dry_run){thread(dry_write,...)}else{thread(write,...)}?

Comment: @JonasK, I would go with impl approach, I think it is cleaner, though effectively the same thing.

Comment: mh, interesting. I haven't come across of a void function returning a void function so I need to put some thought into that. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Usually I'm all for compile-time computation.  But when talking to io, the disk is going to be slower than a virtual pointer indirection every block of data.

So I'd rewrite your code to have a sink.

```
template<class T>
using sink = std::function<void(T)>;

void sink_queue(queue_type& queue, sink<buffer_type&> dest) {
  buffer_type buf;
  while(queue.pop(buf))
    dest(buf);
}
void write(queue_type &queue, bool dry_run, const struct options &opts){
  auto dataset = opts.dataset;
  sink<buffer_type&> dwrite = [](buffer_type&){};
  if (!dry_run)
    dwrite = [&](buffer_type& buf) {
      dset.write(buf);
    };
  sink_queue(queue, dwrite);
}
```

you can go further and implement `operator|` to pipe sources into sinks and remove the type erasure.  But seems too much.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) I might do:

```
auto queue2src(queue_type& queue){
  return [&](auto&& sink)
    buffer_type buf;
    while(queue.pop(buf))
      sink(buf);
  };
}
void write(queue_type &queue, bool dry_run, const struct options &opts){
  auto dataset = opts.dataset;
  dispatch(dry_run,
    [&](buffer_type& buf) {
      dset.write(buf);
    },
    [](buffer_type&){}
  )( queue2src(queue) );
}
```

where `dispatch( index, Ts&&...ts )( func )` invokes `func` with the index-th `ts` without type erasure.

But again, probably too far.